# Tracking eye pupil in camera preview, with most watched part of the screen

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-camera, http-live-streaming

I have live camera preview, now project requires eye pupil movement tracking (which is different from Eye is open/close). Means which part of the screen is being seen by the user this time and what is the most viewed part of screen at the end of Video stream. Although, I tried with OpenCV & Google Vision api, but they are not able to perform the task perfectly.
Please suggest if you have any solution.

https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c

https://developers.google.com/vision/